# search for text in javascript and get all its start and end index

Tags: javascript

I have a content like

> The apple is the pomaceous fruit of the apple tree, species Malus
>   domestica in the rose family (Rosaceae). It is one of the most widely
>   cultivated tree fruits,  apple is the good for and the most widely
>   known of the many members of genus Malus that are used by humans.
>   Apples grow on small, deciduous trees.

I have an array like

```
["apple", " ", "is", " ", "the"];
```

With this array how to find the start index and end index of the word **apple is the** in javascript?

I tried looping the content and using `indexOf` but I couldn't get all the index of the word

this is what i tried

```
var matchs =[];
var content = "a b c defgh a b csdwda abcdfd";
var arrayWord =["a"," ", "b"];
var w =0;
var pos =0;
var firstIndex = content.indexOf(arrayWord[w],pos);
pos = firstIndex;
while (pos > -1) {
    pos+=arrayWord[w].length;
    w++; 
    pos = content.indexOf(arrayWord[w], pos);
    matchs.push(firstIndex,pos);
}
```

Comment: I did not format your question because I'm unsure what you mean by "content". You used `h5` tags for the text, do you actually have the text on page or do you just have a string and tried to format it here with `h5` tags? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: i just have a string and formatted it with h5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your comments I think this is what you are after. You can add further replace statements if necessary.

```
var text,
    pos,
    start,
    matches = [],
    charArr,
    charText,
    currentMatch;

text = $("h5").text( );

//white spaces must match length of string being replaced
text = text.replace("\r\n","    ");
charText = text.split("");

charArr = ["apple", " ", "is", " ", "the"].join("").split("");
currentMatch = 0;

// Loop through char array ignoring multiple white spaces
for( pos = 0; pos < text.length; pos += 1 ) {

    if( currentMatch === 0 ) start = pos;

    if( charText[pos] === charArr[currentMatch] ) {
        currentMatch += 1;      
    } else if( charText[pos] !== " " ) {
        currentMatch = 0;
    }

    // matched entire array so push to matches
    if( currentMatch === charArr.length ) {     
        matches.push( [ start, pos] );
        currentMatch = 0;
    }
}
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gFgz2/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I've understood your question correctly, you can `join` the array and use the `indexOf` method of the string to get the start index (this example assumes your string is stored in `str` and your array is stored in `arr`):

```
var start = str.indexOf(arr.join(""));
```

You could also get rid of the spaces from your array and pass the space to `join` instead, for a smaller array.

Comment: i cant join the array and search, actually  my content may contains unwanted spaces like \n \r etc i need to skip that too and search that's y i used array

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = $("h5").text(); // Get the text from your h5.
var searchText = "apple is the";
var found = []
function findAll(string) {
  var startIdx = string.search(searchText);
  var endIdx = startIdx + searchText.length;
  if(startIdx == -1) {
    return;
  }
  else {
    found.append([startIdx, endIdx]);
    findAll(string.substring(endIdx, string.length));
  }
}
findAll(text);
```

This will recursively search the string until all instances of `searchText` is found.

Each occurrence is stored as a list of begin and end indexes `[[start, end],[start,end],...]` in `found`

Comment: ya but i need the indexOf all occurrences

Comment: Ok see my edit. This is finding the `character` indexes, not the string indexes.

Comment: Thanks Aesthete, if i use sting.search(), i will skip the word like apple is \n the i also need to match the same word having the unwanted spaces